# LaTeX как быть с русским текстом?

Tags: latex

Здравствуйте. пытаюсь ввести этот текст в Texmaker, через pdfLaTeX сконвертировать в PDF-файл, но в итоге получаю пустой лист.
что делать?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
% Эта строка — комментарий, она не будет показана в выходном файле  
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Включаем поддержку UTF8  
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского языка  
\title{\LaTeX}  
\date{}  
\author{}

\begin{document}  
  \maketitle  
  \LaTeX{} "--- это своего рода препроцессор текста для \TeX{} "---  
  программы компьютерной вёрстки. \LaTeX{} является программируемым и  
  расширяемым, что позволяет автоматизировать большую часть аспектов  
  набора, включая нумерацию, перекрёстные ссылки, таблицы и изображения  
  (их размещение и подписи к ним), общий вид страницы, библиографию и  
  многое-многое другое. \LaTeX{} был первоначально написан Лэсли Лампортом  
  в 1984-м году и стал наиболее популярным способом использования \TeX{}а;  
  очень мало людей сегодня пишут на оригинальном \TeX{}е. Текущей  
  версией является \LaTeXe.  
  \newline  
  \begin{eqnarray}  
    E &=& mc^2\\  
    m &=& \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}  
  \end{eqnarray}  
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Без проблем 

       This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)

Comment: Эээ... А какая кодировка у вашего файла _на самом деле_? Убедитесь, что у вас таки utf8.

Comment: utf8 я убедился

Comment: Хм. Странно. А то же самое с английским текстом работает?

Comment: @Илья Михневич а .log посмотреть можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А какие ошибки выдаёт?

Попробуйте заменить

```
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Включаем поддержку UTF8
```

на

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Включаем поддержку UTF8
```

MikTex 2.9 правильно отображает.

Comment: Собирает без ошибки, но файла ПДФ найти не могу

Comment: `\usepackage{ucs}` он же вроде для ссылок/букмарок нужен. Иначе там крякозябры вместо русских (если не путаю)

Comment: я не знаю. я первый раз его запустил, а у меня даже простой пример из википедии не работает.  
because linux, как говорится

Comment: Ну если Вы не заметили, у меня тоже не винды. Правда не совсем Debian, а ubuntu 12.04. Ваш пример создал pdf,  который смотрел и gv, и evince.

Comment: а мой Ubuntu 12.04 ничего не создал.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего эта проблема уже давно решена, но на всякий случай - вставьте строчку

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

после

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

ПОПРАВКА: эта строчка теперь не обязательна - достаточно изменить utf8 на utf8x. Мало того, если у вас вставлен T2A, то как указано в комментарии ниже (**Dmitry Nosachev**), эта вставка приведет к тому, что скопированный из PDF файла русский текст окажется закодированным в чем-то типа KOI-8 вместо стандартной Windows кодировки.

Answer (score 2):

У меня почему-то PDF из pdfLaTeX начиная с какого-то момента начал выдавать крякозябры при копировании текста. Texlive под Windows. Поправил преамбулу, убрав T2A, и всё стало хорошо:

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{cmap}
```

Comment: На данный момент (кто его знает, вдруг что-то обновят) очень рекомендуется первым номером ставить \usepackage{cmap}, а потом уже остальные пакеты. Причина: если этого не сделать, то в скомпилированном PDF файле не будет работать поиск по русским словам.

Comment: В итоге я давно отказался от обычного pdflatex в пользу XeLaTeX.

Comment: Ну не знаю... мне кажется, что единственная причина перейти на XeLaTeX (если конечно pdfLaTeX  у вас работает) в том, что там более удобный доступ с разнообразным шрифтам. А так pdfLaTeX все таки работает вполне надежно. С другой стороны, если вы перешли и у вас все отлично работает, так почему бы и нет. Вариаций много. Тут главное, чтобы ваши коллеги или издательства могли без проблем компилировать ваши исходники.