# Latex на Mac OS

Tags: macos, latex

Простите, пожалуйста, но я уже перепробовала все, что только можно и нельзя.
Исходные данные: Mac OS El Capitan, свежий MacTex, свежий Texmaker (в порыве отчаяния все сносила и переустанавливала).

Раньше Texmaker с грехом пополам компилил файлы с кодировкой cp1251, которые достались мне в наследство от предыдущего ноутбука, после обновления оси перестал воспринимать и их, выдавая неизменное

> Font T2A/cmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

В те редкие и не совсем понятные мне моменты, когда эта ошибка на каком-нибудь тестовом "Привет, мир!" в utf-8 не вылезает, возникает проблема другого рода, которую я силилась исправить в течение нескольких лет: при использовании математики, \it, \bf - в общем, всего, что хоть как-то нарушает благообразную структуру нетронутого русского повествования - вылетает уже с

> Font T2A/cmr/m/it/12=lati1200 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
>   found.

или

> Font T2A/cmr/bx/n/12=labx1200 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

Собственно, именно такие ошибки привели к убогому использованию Windows'ских .tex-файлов.

У меня стоят шрифты cm-super, я проверяла [народными методами](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88368/how-do-i-invoke-cm-super).

Простейшая рабочая шапка, которая и ругается на **жирный** и *курсив*, имеет вид:

> \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
>
> \usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
>
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
>
> \usepackage[russian, english]{babel}

Не посылайте, пожалуйста, на tex.stackexchange, там русских нет, а здесь я видела подобные [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/222769/latex-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC).

Comment: Подождите, не совсем понятно, чего вы хотите. Вы хотите скомпилировать файлы в cp1251? Или в utf-8? Ваш файл с «шапкой» сам в какой кодировке?

Comment: @VladD Я оставила надежду с cp1251, он кривоватый, решила окончательно перейти на utf-8, файл в нем, в настройках тоже он

Comment: Окей, а при проверке «народными средствами», какой путь к шрифтам? Какие pfb-файлы лежат там ещё? Есть ли `labx1200`? Возможно, у вас недоустановились шрифты.

Comment: @VladD Их два: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/
enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t2a.enc И /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1200.pfb. Обе скрытые. В папке с .pfb labx1200 нет, однако поиск выявил, что есть файл labx1200.mf в ~/Library/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/source/lh/lh-t2a, причём тут папки уже открытые.

Comment: Хм, выглядит как-то не очень. Это по идее значит, что шрифты cm-super не стали как надо. (Попробуйте, например, в народном методе использовать `\it` в английском тексте, должно точно так же не сработать.)

Comment: @VladD Спасибо за помощь, проблема пусть и странно, но решилась (см.комментарий к ответу ниже).

Comment: Ну вот и хорошо. Удачи вам!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вероятно, у вас не хватает шрифтов, которые в дистрибутивах *gnu/linux* ставятся пакетами *texlive-lang-cyrillic* и/или *texlive-fonts-recommended*.

не знаю, что за программы (и каким образом) вы устанавливали, но если под *mactex* вы подразумеваете вот [это](http://www.tug.org/mactex/), то, вероятно, вам надо установить и [*mactextras*](http://www.tug.org/mactex/mactextras.html)

Comment: Я тоже так думаю, но так и не выяснила, как это исправляется. Под MacTex именно это и подразумевается, а вот MacTexTras выглядят как уже бывшие в комплекте (потому как у меня стоит все, что они положили в Extras). Ничего про шрифты там нет.

Comment: возможно, что-то не донастроилось в базе данных *ls-R*. в *gnu/linux* она пересоздаётся программой `mktexlsr` (синоним — `texhash`). для пересоздания обще-системной базы данных запускается она с *root*-овыми привилегиями. возможно, у вас в системе есть либо подобная программа, либо какая-нибудь «gui-кнопка» запускающая такую процедуру.

Comment: Как оказалось, тут что-то похожее. К сожалению, я понимаю принципы работы консоли и терминала только на уровне копипасты, однако выяснилось, что все недоустановившиеся файлы лежат в missfont.log и доустанавливаются командой `mktextfm larm1000` (для larm1000, в частности, ну и аналогично для других) из терминала. Это **полностью** решило проблему, вплоть до запуска вышеупомянутых старых файлов с Винды.